# Charge distribution on a conductor surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

I understand that if a conductor was charged with a charge of say 1 coulomb, the charge would spread uniformly over it's entire surface to neutralize any difference in potential. However, and though this would obviously not be something done practically, what would happen if you added just one electron to the metal sphere.

Obviously the electron is incapable of splitting to distribute charge uniformly.
So would the electron just keep moving around the surface of the conductor? This would imply that the electric field just outside the conducting sphere wouldn't need to be perpendicular to it at all points.

Comment: When you add one electron, all the other electrons will also move a little. There is also thermal movement and, since conductors have to be described with quantum mechanics, a slightly more complicated picture of the charge state in such systems than electromagnetism alone suggests.

Comment: Well it probably breaks down at that point.  But it helps to remember that the situation is different than a single free electron; you have a sea of ions and electrons in most cases, which means the 'one additional charge' can be distributed, and needn't be localized.

Comment: So the charge would be uniformly distributed nonetheless? The surface charge density of the sphere surface would increase slightly but still remain constant for all area elements on the sphere?

Comment: What @CuriousOne is saying is basically what I've tried to say in different words.

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaks down'?

Comment: Not uniformly in the sense of uniform area density. It would be nice if it did that, but that doesn't lead to a constant surface potential, except in the case of spherical systems. The mathematical solution of the problem is non-trivial and can, for general shapes, only be found numerically.

Comment: Certainly more uniform than a single electron on a sphere, but electrostatics likely will not hold, in such simple form, in this low charge carrier limit.  the macroscopic treatment you're referring to treats charge like a continuous 'fluid'; if a single electron becomes important, this model may no longer hold.

Comment: so basically except for spherical surfaces which act as equipotential surfaces,  most arbitrary 3 dimensional shapes would have constant potential differences between two arbitrary points of their surface?

Comment: breaks down -> no longer valid in the scenario you mention.

Comment: No, they would not have potential differences, big ones anyway.  But they would have fluctuations on some level.

Comment: due to the constant flow of delocalized charges?

Comment: It really depends in which approximation we are working. For quantum mechanical solutions on small bodies (and/or extremely low temperatures) not even the average potential will be constant, e.g. in the case of molecules or single electron transistors, etc.. For macroscopic conductors the average potential will be constant, but there will be a local, temperature and geometry dependent fluctuation.

Comment: @CuriousOne Do the electrons on the conductor continuously move to accomodate this electron? Let's ignore the fact that we're dealing with a system where a single electron matters and consider a macroscopic domain for a second. There would be uniform charge density but if the electrons kept moving, there would be a magnetic field produced even though no current passes through the conductor. Considering here a spherical surface.

Comment: One couldn't actually distinguish between the electrons in the conductor and "the extra" electron. Are there currents in the thermal case? Of course, the body keeps radiating and, in return, it absorbs radiation from the environment which it is in thermal equilibrium with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If electrons obeyed classical mechanics, they would rearrange in a new configuration in order to maximize the distance between them. They would not stay still because of thermal motion, as pointed out by CuriousOne, but on average they will still maximize this distance.

However, electrons don't obey classical mechanics, but [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure). The behavior of electrons in a conductor is more like that of *waves* (a plane wave in the [free electron model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model), which is the crudest approximation). So the electron are delocalized on the whole surface of the conductor and it is probably more meaningful to talk about a single charge density function $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ rather than talking about individual electrons.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons in metals have states which people call Bloch states. If we want to describe these states we should bear in mind that electrons have wave like behavior. Bloch states are a subset of the many infinite wave states which electrons can have in general. They're such that when an electron is in a Bloch state, it somehow fills everywhere in the metal. If you are familiar with the problem of a quantum mechanical particle in a box, you understand what I mean. So when we add a new electron to a metal, it spreads all over the metal, and hence it produces a uniform charge density(if we put away the effect of boundaries).